# ¿Cómo obtener datos y generarlos aleatoriamente?

Tags: php, mysqli

En la evaluación existen 4 alternativas de opciones pero que no funciona de manera manera aleatoria.

```
'alternatives' => [$row["a1"], $row["a2"],$row["a3"],$row["a4"]],
```

que es igual a:

```
'alternatives' => [1, 2, 3, 4],
```

Esa información es obtenida por las siguientes columnas

```
a1    a2    a3    a4
1     2     3      4
2a1b   3c2a y4x1   2v7a
```

Y su visualización tomando cuenta la primer fila es:

```
A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
```

Pero como puedo recibir esos datos de manera aleatoria por ejemplo:

```
 'alternatives' => [4, 2, 1, 3],
```

Para luego así al repetir una evaluación, las respuestas correctas no estén en la misma letra especifica.

```
A) 4
B) 2
C) 1
D) 3
```

Este es mi código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE enabled=yes";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $answers[] = [
        'name' => 'respuesta_'.$row["id_question"],
        'question' => $row["question"],
        'alternatives' => [$row["a1"], $row["a2"],$row["a3"],$row["a4"]],
        'answer' => $row["answer"]
    ];
}

$questions = [];

foreach($answers as $index => $answer) {
    $questions[]=$answer;
    $questions[$index]['answer']=null;
}
```

Ejemplo de datos a obtener

```
    [
        'name'         => 'respuesta_1',
        'question'     => 'Cuanto es 2+2?',
        'alternatives' => [1, 2, 3, 4],
        'answer'    => 4,
    ]
```

Estructura de la tabla de datos

```
id_question     question     a1     a2     a3     a4     answer     category
.........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es la función `shuffle()`

http://php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE enabled=yes";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // pasamos el array a una variable
    $lista = [$row["a1"], $row["a2"],$row["a3"],$row["a4"]];
    // ahora desordenamos al "azar"
    shuffle ( $lista );


    $answers[] = [
        'name' => 'respuesta_'.$row["id_question"],
        'question' => $row["question"],
        'alternatives' => $lista,
        'answer' => $row["answer"]
    ];
}

$questions = [];

foreach($answers as $index => $answer) {
    $questions[]=$answer;
    $questions[$index]['answer']=null;
}
```